# How to prove SPACE-TMSAT is PSPACE-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, space-complexity

I understand that the language:

$\operatorname{SPACE-TMSAT} = \{⟨M, w, 1^n⟩ : \text{DTM $M$ accepts $w$ in space $n$}\}$

is in PSPACE since it doesn't use more than $n$ space. But to prove that it is PSPACE-complete, we need to do the reduction from any other PSPACE language to it. If we assume the language to run on a DTM using $O(n^k)$ space, how could we reduce it to SPACE-TMSAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $L$ is accepted by some machine $M$ using up to $p(n)$ space, for some polynomial $p(n)$. We map $w$ to $\langle M, w, 1^{p(|w|)} \rangle$.

Comment: thank you! I guess we assume in the definition of SPACE TMSAT, n is the size of the input.

Comment: No, $n$ is completely arbitrary.

Comment: So the input is a binary string consisting Turing machine, machine's input, and a number of ones at the end?

Comment: That's just right.